# Query multiple fields with single query string and words in any order

Tags: elasticsearch

I thought the scenario must be quite common, but I was unable to find any clues on how to progress.

I've got an elasticsearch index that contains single type `Order`. In turn, `Order` contains `Customer` information, such as `firstName`, `lastName`, `middleName` (and their concatenation  `fullName`), e.g.

```
"order": {
    // other stuff
    "customer": {
        "firstName": ...,
        "lastName": ...,
        "middleName": ...,
        "fullName": "FirstName MiddleName LastName"
    }
}
```

The aim is to provide order search functionality, including search by customers' names. The input to the elastic would always be a single query string, containing whatever user typed into a search box. The problem is there are some dirty data (e.g. missing firstName, swapped first and last name, etc.) and I can't rely on users always input names in certain order.

I've tried achieving that with `query_string` query like this:

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "[User Input]*", // note asterisk here
    "fields" : ["customer.firstName", "customer.lastName", "customer.middleName"],
    "analyzer": "whitespace",
    "use_dis_max": true,
    "tie_breaker": 0.7,
    "analyze_wildcard": true
}
```

It does a decent work of finding the results in some cases, but it's definitely not robust against dirty data, e.g. it finds John Doe's order if searching for "John Do" (not a typo), but fails to do so if searching for "Doe John".

Desired query behavior would be something like `match_phrase_prefix` on multiple fields with `whitespace` analyzer to process query and do a prefixing on *each* term coming out from analyzer. As an example, `John Doe` would be turned into something like `["John*", "Doe*"]` and each applied to

- `firstName`, `lastName`, `middleName` fields
- or to `fullName` allowing individual terms to come in any order

I'm really new to elastic, so I might be missing something really simple, or not confident enough to write really complex queries.

**Edit**: index mappings: http://pastebin.com/fuLLgHjB. Target fields are not yet analyzed because: (1) I'm not the one made an initial setup and (2) I'm really not sure what field analyzers should I set up, so it's a part of the question.

Comment: Can you show your mappings for the name fields?  Are they analyzed?  If not, why not?

Comment: @kielni, updated the question with mappings setup.

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch has really good defaults.  You should start out with the defaults, and only add/change settings if something is not working the way you want.  Simpler is better.

When setting up your mappings, the default for string fields is to analyze them.  This is a good thing because breaks the strings into tokens and does stemming, so that you can do partial and fuzzy matches.  You don't need to specify the analyzer; the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) should work fine.  A not analyzed field means Elasticsearch won't do anything to the field; this is useful for things like faceting (count the number of orders by each of "John", "Jon", and "Jonathan"), but not as much for general full-text searching.  If you really think you need a not analyzed version of the field, you can include the same field both analyzed and not analyzed with multi-fields; see the [multi-field docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html) for more info.

Here's a sample mapping; you may not even need to generate the `fullName` field.

```
    "properties": {
      "firstName": { "type": "string" },
      "lastName": { "type": "string" },
      "middleName": { "type": "string" },
      "fullName": { "type": "string" }
    }
```

Once your fields are analyzed, the order of terms in the query doesn't have to match exactly, the spelling doesn't have to be perfect, etc.  Try the simplest query and it should work pretty well:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "John Doe",
      "fields": [
        "firstName",
        "middleName",
        "lastName"
      ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If it's not ordering the results in the way you expect, you could try replacing non-trailing whitespace in the query string with an AND, to require all terms: `John AND Doe`